# launchWebFlow in firefox extension closes the extension window on oauth2 popup

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon-webextensions

So I am running into an interesting issue and would like some opinions. So I have a chrome extension that I am porting over to a firefox extension. Everything is working perfect besides this stupid issue I am having. Basically, when I initiate launchWebAuthFlow, the oauth2 window pops up like it should, but for some reason in firefox it closes the extension window when the oauth2 popup opens, which completely voids the login process since the extension is closed. On chrome, when the oauth2 page opens the extension window still stays open, but in firefox it closes immediately. It seems to be because in firefox they open the oauth2 page in a completely new firefox window instead of the nice little popup chrome does. Does anyone have any experience with this issue and perhaps have a fix or workaround? I do not really think I need to attach code to this but I will for the lols.

```
    chrome.identity.launchWebAuthFlow(
        { url: auth_url, interactive: true },
        function (redirect_url) {
```

Comment: same problem here. Did you find a solution?

Comment: @andrea.spot. yeah I found a solution, give me a bit and ill answer this questions with my solution when I have a few mins.

Comment: Any update on this? Ran into the same issue.

Comment: @Karl I ended up basically setting up my oauth2 in a background script and had it activate on extension button click.

Comment: Can you give a snippet on how you have done it? I'm facing the same problem, can't get the token after the user authorizes because it closes..

Comment: Pinging for same issue as @PedroSilva. Did you have any luck?

Comment: Yeah I did, basically I moved the launcWebAuthFlow call to the background script. For that, I used this repo https://github.com/mozilla/webextension-polyfill it has the backs. If you want a real example, here is mine https://github.com/PedroS11/twitch-live-extension/blob/master/src/background.ts 

The store sends a message to the backgorund script for a token (fetchToken method), and then just return it
Hope it helps you